# Alert with progress bar similar to toast JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make an alert with descending progress bar. I need that when the mouse passes over the alert, the progress bar will stop and when I remove the mouse it will continue where it left off. After completing 5 sec, it closes by itself. I put the option when clicking on the alert, close it, but it is optional.

Below is the code I made:

```js
var currentChunk = 0;
var chunks = 5;

$('.alert').click(function() {
  $(".alert").alert('close');
});

$('.alert').hover(function() {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  window.clearTimeout(time);
  $(".alert").css('opacity', 1);
}, function() {
  $(".alert").css('opacity', .9);
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    update();
  }, 10);
});

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  update();
}, 10);

var time = window.setTimeout(function() {
  $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}, ((chunks - currentChunk) * 1000));

function update() {
  currentChunk += 0.01;
  var progPercent = 100 - (currentChunk * (100 / chunks));
  $(".progress-bar").css('width', progPercent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', progPercent);

  if (progPercent <= 0) {
    $(".alert").remove();
  }

  if (currentChunk >= 5) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.alert {
  position: relative;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="alert" role="alert" style="cursor:pointer;opacity:.85">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
  <div class="progress active" role="progressbar" style="height:5px">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" id="pb" style="width:100%;opacity:0.5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are two errors I want to correct. When the mouse is placed over the alert, the progress bar decrements beyond where it was and before the progress bar ends, it closes the alert.

Comment: The first issue may be caused by a too short interval time. I tried making your function run every 200ms instead of 10 (and editing the chunk increment accordingly), and the issue seems less noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by an easing transition on the progress bar from bootstrap's styles. In other words, the actual progress is further along than you think, because the easing function makes the visuals lag.

If you remove the transition, it works as expected.

```js
var currentChunk = 0;
var chunks = 5;

$('.alert').click(function() {
  $(".alert").alert('close');
});

$('.alert').hover(function() {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  window.clearTimeout(time);
  $(".alert").css('opacity', 1);
}, function() {
  $(".alert").css('opacity', .9);
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    update();
  }, 10);
});

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  update();
}, 10);

var time = window.setTimeout(function() {
  $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}, ((chunks - currentChunk) * 1000));

function update() {
  currentChunk += 0.01;
  var progPercent = 100 - (currentChunk * (100 / chunks));
  $(".progress-bar").css('width', progPercent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', progPercent);

  if (progPercent <= 0) {
    $(".alert").remove();
  }

  if (currentChunk >= 5) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.alert {
  position: relative;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.progress-bar {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="alert" role="alert" style="cursor:pointer;opacity:.85">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
  <div class="progress active" role="progressbar" style="height:5px">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" id="pb" style="width:100%;opacity:0.5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue seems caused by a too short time interval. It appears that the delay between the CSS width changing and the UI actually updating is greater than 10 ms.

However, `setInterval` will always call the `update` function at 10ms interval, regardless of whether the UI finished updating or not. So, the delay in UI piles up quickly.

A possible fix is to make the interval longer (I made it 200 ms in the demo below), and changing the chunk size increment accordingly (so I did `currentChunk += interval/1000;` instead of 0.01) so that the animation stays relatively smooth.

---

For the second issue, it seems your two timers (`time` and `timer`) are somehow out of sync. But why keep both anyway? A possible solution using only the `timer` interval is shown below.

```js
var currentChunk = 0;
var chunks = 5;
var interval = 200;

$('.alert').click(function() {
  $(".alert").alert('close');
});

$('.alert').hover(function() {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  $(".alert").css('opacity', 1);
}, function() {
  $(".alert").css('opacity', .9);
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    update();
  }, interval);
});

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  update();
}, interval);

function update() {
  currentChunk += interval/1000;
  var progPercent = 100 - (currentChunk * (100 / chunks));
  $(".progress-bar").css('width', progPercent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', progPercent);

  if (progPercent <= 0) {
    removeAlert();
  }

  if (currentChunk >= 5) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

//function that removes alert
function removeAlert() {
  $(".alert").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.alert {
  position: relative;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="alert" role="alert" style="cursor:pointer;opacity:.85">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
  <div class="progress active" role="progressbar" style="height:5px">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" id="pb" style="width:100%;opacity:0.5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```